# "Tried to start delayed item" ... "but failed" in output of apt-get install

Tags: apt, dpkg

I've recently started to use new distro (Linux Mint 21, which I've read is based on Ubuntu 22.04). And when installing some packages I often see many same lines near end of `apt-get install` output:

"Tried to start delayed item" http...ubuntu jammy package-name "but failed"

Web search for "Tried to start delayed item"  "but failed" found only couple of links, with bugs (I saw only submission of bugs, no discussion). I also was not able to find "delayed item" for apt-get, what it is.

What those delayed items are and what does the error mean? TIA

Comment: To add: it was noted when I run `apt-get install /somepath/*.deb` when offline.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `deb` files to dpkg cache folder (usually `/var/cache/apt/archives/`) and run `apt-get install /cache_folder/*.deb`, no such warnings noted if done that way.

**TL;DR**

As noted in my comment to the question, the warning is when installing deb files in offline mode, the code that produces it is in `aquire.cc` (https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt.git):

```
if (I->Items->Owner->Status == pkgAcquire::Item::StatIdle)
        {
           _error->Warning("Tried to start delayed item %s, but failed", I->Items->Description.c_str());
        }
```

From many test runs I noted that when deb files are in cache folder, `apt` does not try to re-aquire (download from repos). When deb files somewhere else, `apt` tries to aquire packages corresponding to `deb` files, hence "Note: selecting packagename instead of debfile" in output for every? deb file (not sure why, maybe in case newer versions are available?).

Seems there is some timeout for trying to get packages from repos after which it gives up (e.g. when run in terminal number of warnings was ~500, but when output directly redirected to file it was ~7000. ). Why warnings are only for some rare "delayed items", I had not identified.

I have not noticed deficiencies in functionality after install either (cache vs. some other folder) way, however the number of lines of "tried to start" was sometimes in thousands and they presented issues for reading output.

I've been able to reperform with Linux Mint 21 liveISO and set of 3 deb files (these are part of sqlitebrowser, e.g. `apt-get install --download-only sqlitebrowser`):

```
libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n_2.11.6+dfsg-4_amd64.deb
libqscintilla2-qt5-15_2.11.6+dfsg-4_all.deb
libqtprintsupport5_5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

Interestingly the warning lists libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n which has no dependencies and when installed by its own (right after liveISO boot) does not result in warnings.